# Highcharts Zooming with Scroll Bar

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts there is a nice feature to zoom and pane the area. But in order to use panning - it should be in combination with a shift key as mentioned in the example here. Is there a way to display a scroll bar on zoom in instead of panning?

Comment: Hi, Have you seen Highstock charts? I think this charts can meet your requirements. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: yes, but i don't wanna use highstock.

Comment: You can use scrollbar in Highcharts if you add highstock.js library. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3571/

Comment: Is it possible to add scrollbar without using highstock library?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to have Highstock license if you want to use scrollbar/navigator. But if you have license for Highcharts you can contact sales team, maybe they will offer you something. I think that it is possible to make your custom scrollbar, using renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use renderer and make your custom scrollbar with it:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect

You can make two rectangles, one for your scrollbar background and second for your scrolling button.

You can change their attributes using attr():
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.attr

```
chart.renderer.rect(0, height - 60, width, 20)
      .attr({
        fill: '#666',
        zIndex: 3,
        visibility: 'hidden'
      }).addClass('scroll')
      .add();
```

You can use afterSetExtremes event and inside its callback function you can connect visibility of your scrollbar with visibility of your reset zoom button:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

You need to calculate width of your scrollbar and x position. You can do it by simple math proportion of your axis min and max and width of your chart. For example you can set your width inside redraw event callback function:

```
    redraw: function() {
      var chart = this;
      this.xAxis[0].displayBtn ? ($('.scrollBar').show() && $('.scroll').show()) : ($('.scrollBar').hide() && $('.scroll').hide())
      width = chart.chartWidth;
      newWidth = width * (max - min) / (oldMax - oldMin);
      $('.scroll').attr({
        width: width
      });
      $('.scrollBar').attr({
        width: newWidth,
        x: width * min / oldMax,
      });
    }
```

You need to add mousedown and mousemove events to your scrollbar. You can do it using jQuery. Inside mousemove event you need to recalculate x position of your scroll button basing on your mouse position:

```
$('.scrollBar').on('mousedown', function() {
        var mousePos;
        $(this).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
          $(this).attr({
            x: e.clientX + 70,
          })
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min - ((mousePos || e.clientX) - e.clientX) * oldMax / width, max - ((mousePos || e.clientX) - e.clientX) * oldMax / width, true, false);
          mousePos = e.clientX;

        });
      })
```

Here you can see an example how it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/LnneuLoy/8/

Kind regards.

Comment: this is awesome! I made a slightly updated version that adds the `mousemove` on the document level instead, makes scrolling smoother:
http://jsfiddle.net/LnneuLoy/20/